# how to import custom css to reactjs project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jsx

I'm really struggling to get a custom bootstrap.min.css into my react project does anyone know how to do this as there isn't much documentation on how to do this or maybe i'm just blind and cant see it

Thanks

Edit: ive tried  in my index.html head and it doesnt work

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 
                    'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false 
           }),
  ],
};
```

thats my webpack

I am unsure of what the best css loader is if anyone can suggest one that would be great

edit 2

```
<div className="container" style={backImg}>
                <div className="row" style={slidePadding}>
                    <div className="col-md-12 well well-lg">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <h4>Thinking load from £200 to £3,000? Thinking of repaying from 6 - 24 months? </h4><br />
                                <Horizontal />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div  className="col-md-12">
                                <p>Representative Example. Borrow £1,250 - 15 monthly repayments of £166.66. Total cost of credit £1,249.90 which is £1,249.90 interest at 122.96% pa fixed. Total amount repayable £2,499.90. Representative 233.6% APR.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is the main section of the site which you land on

this is basically where i want the css to work on i want to be able to change all the widths and everything so doing it in inline style would be horrible so css file is the only way

Comment: in the `head` of your index.html

Comment: Just include the CSS like you would for any other project, just because it's react doesn't make it any different.

Comment: you have to do import of the file path. For example => 
import a from "../styles/bootstap.min.css";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself what i needed to do was in my index.html was add

```
<link href="./js/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then install

```
npm install --save-dev ignore-loader
```

then in webpack.config.js add

```
loader: 'babel-loader', 'ignore-loader',
```

the ignore-loader part and it tells babel not to transpile css files

Answer (score 0):

You have to do import of the file path in your component(JS) file.For example:

```
import a from "../styles/bootstap.min.css";
```

Comment: How do i then call that @Vinay Gayakwad

Comment: it gives me an Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../bootstap.min.css" i imported it into my client.js which is my main js file

Comment: After importing you can add normal class names in DOM element. But note, in ReactJS the attribute of the class has to be replaced with "className". For example => <div className="active"></div>

Here active is your class defined in css file. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Cannot find module means the path you have given is wrong. It is relative path. SO you have to check with the file location exactly and modify according to it. My example was just to understand. Exact code doesn't work. You may have to modify as per your file structure.

Comment: I have done and pointed it exactly where it is ill have to try and mess with it thanks for the clarification

Comment: it is saying that it cant parse the css file also its still saying cant find the module but then it goes on to say it cant parse it

Comment: Are you using webpack config and added loaders there? If not you may have to look into it once. It will be easier to understand the issue with code snippet or working fiddler.

Comment: im not sure how to use jsfiddle doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: It is difficult to give solutions by assumption without knowing what is the actual issue. You can add some code snippets in your question, related to this issue.

Comment: you got any suggestions why it still isnt working ive tried to work it out but i got nothing

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import the css file in the root of your app.
see whats the root of your app and just import the file there.
like :
import '../pathToTheFile';
thats it.